# Why is the result of my random forest model not capturing changes in one of my predictor variables?

Tags: r, random-forest

I am trying to utilize a random forest to create a model, but the predictions I am getting from this model seem to be identical even when the value of my "Group" variable changes. Here is my code:

```
test = randomForest(Preg.ended ~ Group*prop_score_b, data = train_prop)
perio_treat <- perio_cont <- test_prop
perio_treat$Group = "T"
perio_cont$Group = "C"
pred1_preg_b <- predict(test, newdata = perio_treat, type = "response")
pred0_preg_b <- predict(test, newdata = perio_cont, type = "response")
ATE_preg_b <- mean(pred1_preg_b - pred0_preg_b)
print(ATE_preg_b, digits = 3)
```

To summarize: My model is built with the binary dependent variable `Preg.ended`, which is either 0 or 1, and predictor variables of `Group` which takes on the categorical values of either T or C, and `prop_score_b` which is a continuous variable between 0 and 1. I split my data into `train_prop` and `test_prop` which have equivalent columns and a random 2/3 to 1/3 split of the data. What I am trying to do is to see what results I get if all of my test data has `Group` = T compared to what I would get if `Group` = C. The mean of the difference between these two should have meaning, but the result I am getting is zero, because all of the values in `pred1_preg_b` and `pred0_preg_b` are completely identical to one another. So that would tell me that the change in value of `Group` means nothing in my prediction, and I don't understand why, since it is built into my model.

I have indeed verified that my `train_prop` data set has `Group` values of C and T, so it should be having some predictive value in the results.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Since your code is not reproducible is hard to guess what happens under the hood. This can be caused by the dimension of your data. For instance, if you have a few observations it can happen what you have described. Also, in predicting a binary outcome, a binary predictor can be useless. Look at the variable's importance in your model. It is probable that your `Group` variable has very low importance.
Look at this example:

```
library(randomForest)
set.seed(4)
df <- data.frame(out=as.factor(sample(0:1,1000,replace = T)),group=sample(c("C","T"),100,replace = T),score=runif(100))
index <- sample(1:nrow(df),round(nrow(df)*2/3))

train <- df[index,]
test <- df[-index,]

rf <- randomForest(out ~ group*score, data = train,mtry=1)
varImpPlot(rf)
importance(rf)
test1 <- test2 <- test
test1$group = "T"
test2$group = "C"
pred <- predict(rf, newdata = test)
pred1_preg_b <- predict(rf, newdata = test1)
pred0_preg_b <- predict(rf, newdata = test2)

ATE_preg_a <- mean(as.numeric(pred) - as.numeric(pred1_preg_b))
ATE_preg_b <- mean(as.numeric(pred) - as.numeric(pred0_preg_b))
ATE_preg_c <- mean(as.numeric(pred1_preg_b) - as.numeric(pred0_preg_b))
```

Here the two predictions (`pred1_preg_b` and `pred0_preg_b`) are different.
But if you try to change the seed you will likely get the same result for both predictions. You can calculate the probability of obtaining a different result by running this code for example 10,000 times.

```
result <- as.list(1:10000)

for (i in 1:10000) {
  rf <- randomForest(out ~ group*score, data = train,mtry=1)
  test1 <- test2 <- test
  test1$group = "T"
  test2$group = "C"
  pred1_preg_b <- predict(rf, newdata = test1)
  pred0_preg_b <- predict(rf, newdata = test2)
  result[[i]] <- mean(as.numeric(pred1_preg_b) - as.numeric(pred0_preg_b))
  
}

sum(result==0)
```

In this simulation, I obtained the same prediction for `test1` and `test2` ~ 64% of the time.
For sure it is strange behavior that needs more investigation, but for now, the most probable reason is the low correlation between the outcome and the binary predictor which lead to very low variable importance for the RF model